# How to restrict non-superuser users to delete with Django CBV?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am using a function based view that restricts any `users` except the `superuser` to delete something and route the user to the same page `site-list` regardless if user is restricted or not. It is perfectly working. Here that working code:

```
@login_required
def delete_site(request, pk):

    site = TargetSite.objects.filter(primary_key=pk).first()    

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.user.is_superuser:
        site.delete()
        messages.success(request, f'Successfully deleted "{site.site_name}" ', extra_tags='check')
        return redirect('site-list', project=site.project)
    else:
        messages.warning(request, f'Sorry, you\'re not authorized to execute this request', extra_tags='exclamation')
        return redirect('site-list', project=site.project)
```

However, when I tried the CBV, it does not work same as the function based. The `non-superuser` is able to delete and not restricted:

```
class SiteDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = TargetSite

    def test_func(self):
        site = self.get_object()

        if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
            messages.warning(self.request, f'Sorry, you\'re not authorized to execute this request', extra_tags='exclamation')
            return reverse('site-list', kwargs={'project': site.project})
        return True

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, f'Successfully deleted "{ self.object.site_name}" ', extra_tags='check')
        return reverse('site-list', kwargs={'project': self.object.project})
```

I also tried this one with `test_func(self)`, but it just threw a `403 Forbidden` message and does not route the user to the same `site-list` page. I believe I'm missing something. Can you please help?

```
def test_func(self):       
    if self.request.user.is_superuser:
         return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the dispatch method for CBV

```
# Inside your class SiteDeleteView
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
        messages.warning(self.request, f'Sorry, you\'re not authorized to execute this request', extra_tags='exclamation')
        return reverse('site-list', kwargs={'project': site.project})
    # If it is a superuser continue with the dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```